# Eloquent: get all users that share one or more groups of a user

Tags: eloquent, laravel-5

How would I get all users that share one or more groups of a certain user?

I already have a many-to-many relationship between users and groups with the intermediate table group_user...

I thought using something like this pseudocode:

```
$users = User::with('groups')->whereIn('groups', $current_user->groups->all())->all();
```

Do I need to use `hasManyThrough` somehow?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming that the `group_user` table has the primary key `id`, probably something like below would work.

```
$users = User::whereHas('groups', function ($q) use ($current_user) {
    $q->whereIn('id', $current_user->groups->pluck('id')->all()); 
})->get();
```

Comment: Perfect! I have too little experience to find such things. Thanks